# Can I print something in the middle of a function?

Tags: idris, idris2

One example code on https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html says isSingleton returns Nat when the parameter is True, and returns a list when the parameter is False.

```
isSingleton : Bool -> Type
isSingleton True = Nat
isSingleton False = List Nat
```

Now, can I somehow insert putStrLn "hello world" into `isSingleton True = Nat` so that it first prints my string, then returns Nat?

Comment: Possibly, but that function's only used at the type level. Is that what you want, rather than printing in say `mkSingle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ish ...

You can print things on that line with, forgoing safety,

```
module Main

isSingleton : Bool -> Type
isSingleton True = unsafePerformIO $ do putStrLn "hi"
                                        pure Nat
isSingleton False = List Nat

foo : Type -> String
foo _ = "foo"

main : IO ()
main = putStrLn $ foo $ isSingleton True
```

which prints

```
hi
foo
```

However, it appears you can't then use `isSingleton` in function signatures because Idris doesn't appear to execute the IO machinery when type checking. I get

```
Error: While processing right hand side of mkSingle. Can't find an implementation for Num (unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "hi" >> Delay (pure Nat))).

Main:11:17--11:18
 07 | foo : Type -> String
 08 | foo _ = "foo"
 09 | 
 10 | mkSingle : (x : Bool) -> isSingleton x
 11 | mkSingle True = 0
                      ^
```

But really, I'm very unclear why you'd want to do this at all. If you want to check which branch you're using you could just annotate with `the`. If you wanted to print values not types, there is functionality in the `Debug` module which does the same as the first example above.