# How many times does a type function run, can you prove?

Tags: idris, idris2

People say a dependent type language is slow in type checking so I think it is slow in running type functions.

Use the classic example on https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html

```
isSingleton : Bool -> Type
isSingleton True = Nat
isSingleton False = List Nat

mkSingle : (x : Bool) -> isSingleton x
mkSingle True = 0
mkSingle False = []
```

and run

```
mkSingle True
```

How many times does `isSingleton` run?

In a traditional language, I can print to console. [But Idris doesn't appear to execute the IO machinery when type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105601/can-i-print-something-in-the-middle-of-a-function). I can increase a global counter or set a breakpoint at the beginning of `isSingleton` and count how many times the breakpoint is hit.

Can I do something in idris 2 to easily convince people, "hey, during the time isSingleton has been called x times"?

**Update**

```
f : (x : Bool) -> isSingleton x -> Nat
f True n = 0
f False ls = 1
```

I set the multiplicity of isSingleton to 0, add the above code to my file and run

```
Main> f True []
Error: When unifying:
    List ?a
and:
    isSingleton True
Mismatch between: List ?a and Nat.

(Interactive):1:8--1:10
 1 | f True []
            ^^
```

idris knows the second argument should be Nat, which is provided by `isSingleton`, right? But isSingleton is erased at runtime, how is isSingleton called?

Comment: For the update, `isSingleton` is called when type checking `f True []` not when running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase `isSingleton`

```
0 isSingleton : Bool -> Type
isSingleton True = Nat
isSingleton False = List Nat
```

then you know it doesn't exist at runtime and is never called. I imagine it's also never called (in this example) if you don't erase it, but by erasing it you can be sure.

Comment: But isSingleton is called to check `mkSingle True = 0 mkSingle False = []`, right? So it's called at compile time.. hmmm, it sort of answers my questions.

Comment: Can you see my update? In my revised example, isSingleton is erased but can still be called at runtime?

Comment: @Gqqnbig michael messer is correct. I assumed you were talking just about how many times it's called at runtime, not compile time. I don't know how many times it would be called at compile time